# SQL Server Driver Error Failed to find or load the JDBC driver:

Tags: jdbc, tibco, tibco-business-works, tibco-designer

I am getting below error while trying to connect to **SQL SERVER**. I have already done following and still getting the error:

1. downloaded `Sqljdbc42.jar` file
2. placed it in `"C:\tibco\tpcl\5.9\jdbc"` folder
3. updated designer.tra file - appended *tibco.env.CUSTOM_CP_EXT* and *tibco.env.STD_CP_EXT* with "C:\tibco\tpcl\5.9\lib\sqljdbc42.jar"

I also did tried placing the jar file in `"C:\tibco\tpcl\5.9\lib"` and 
`"C:\tibco\bw\5.12\lib"` folder and repeated Step3 above, however, no luck..

any suggestions ?

**Error:**

> BW-JDBC-100033 "Configuration Test Failed. Failed to find or load the
>   JDBC driver: tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"

Comment: Which driver do you select in TIBCO Designer for your JDBC connection? The class "tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver" comes from the drivers provided by TIBCO.

Comment: Thanks @Retgits, I realized that I was missing the installation of "TIB_dbdrivers_2.0.4_win_x86_64(DB Drivers Supplement)" driver, I installed it now and "tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver" is working like a charm !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver driver comes with tibco BW installation. looks like the tibco tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver driver was not installed in your environment.

If you want to use sqljdbc42.jar you need to specify correct jdbc driver class in Tibco connection configuration in "JDBC Driver" field (please see screenshot).

[image]

For sqljdbc42.jar the "JDBC Driver" is

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

you can find The JDBC driver class name and connection string example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017

the connection string should look like:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks;user=MyUserName;password=*****;
```

as you said you need to add sqljdbc42.jar to C:\tibco\tpcl\5.x\jdbc folder. 
The folder C:\tibco\bw\5.x\lib also works.

You need to restart designer after adding jars.

Comment: Thanks @David, I realized that I was missing the installation of "TIB_dbdrivers_2.0.4_win_x86_64(DB Drivers Supplement)" driver, I installed it now and "tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver" is working like a charm !!!